# Django Rest Framework - how to get __unicode__() values in related fields for ModelSerializers

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

ModelSerializer() will for some reason not display `__unicode__()` values for related models but rather their id - is there a way to fix this? Or I have to somehow explicitly define all related fields? For the related models I use ModelView that utilize HyperlinkedModelSerializer.

Model

```
class ActionItem(CoreBase):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, null=True, blank=True, related_name='ProjectActionItems')
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio, null=True, blank=True, related_name='PortfolioActionItems')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('ActionItem', null=True, blank=True)
    priority = models.ForeignKey(DicPriority, default=ActionItem_default_priority)
    status = models.ForeignKey(DicActionItemStatus, default=ActionItem_initial_status)
    resolution = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    assignee = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='executor')
    due_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Related model (priority):

```
class DicPriority(DicCoreBase):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = '[D] Priority'
        verbose_name_plural = '[D] Priorities'
```

its base class:

```
class DicCoreBase(CoreBase):
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=10, null=False, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['order']

    def __unicode__(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'name'):
            return self.name
        else:
            return u'Dic (%s): %s' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.pk)
```

The Serializer

```
class ActionItemTextSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ActionItem
        fields = ('id', 'created_by', 'created_date', 'project', 'portfolio', 'name', 'description', 'parent', 'priority', 'status')


class ActionItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ActionItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ActionItemTextSerializer
```

The output:

```
{
        "id": 5,
        "created_by": 1,
        "created_date": "2015-03-19T18:34:07Z",
        "project": 1,
        "portfolio": null,
        "name": "NEW TEST!!!",
        "description": "ACE TEST NEW XOXO",
        "parent": null,
        "priority": 2,
        "status": 2
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRF provides Keys for related fields to make navigating between related objects easy. If you want to reference a property of a related field, you can define it explicitly:

```
class ActionItemTextSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    priority_text = serializers.CharField(source='priority')
    class Meta:
        model = ActionItem
        fields = ('id', 'created_by', 'created_date', 'project', 'portfolio', 'name', 'description', 'parent', 'priority_text', 'status')
```

EDIT:
 I initially had `source='priority__name'`, but Kevin pointed out I was using the incorrect syntax and it should have been `source='priority.name'`, but then I re-read the question and it was specifically about `__unicode__`, so it's just a matter of defining your serializer field as a CharField, which will automatically call `__unicode__` on your object. So we end up with `source='priority'`

Comment: @KevinBrown yep. sorry, I wasn't thinking!

Comment: thank you, that surely does it. So this is intentional that the ModelSerializer will ignore the `__unicode__` override on the abstract class (that will return the name of priority) and only fetches the ID? Is there a tag or something that I could use to override this logic and have it use the `__unicode__` fields by default (instead of having to override all individual fields, and there are many...)

Comment: Thats the beauty of the modelserializer, It provides you with the keys to your related objects so you can retrieve them as needed. If you want lots of data, you could add `depth = 1` to your Meta class and it should return all the properties of your related items nested within your object. That may be an option depending on what your data looks like and whether you need to POST back to it.